# In Adobe Priemiere Pro CC, export media window does not appear

Tags: premiere

In Adobe Priemiere Pro CC 2018, when I use the `File > Export > Media` menu item, the export media window does not appear!

I've confirmed that it's not merely hidden behind other windows or on another monitor.

I have up-to-date software (currently version 12.0.0 and I'm running Adobe Media Encoder CC 2018.

Answer (score 7):

Called Adobe support, and they quickly solved the problem.

The export media window apparently *only appears if the currently selected/highlighted workspace panel is either the video timeline panel or the playback panel*. If ***any other panels*** are currently selected instead, the window will fail to appear.